# Python Multiprocessing get hung

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Below is a min. reproducible code:

```
import multiprocessing

class E(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        Exception.__init__(self, '{}{}'.format(a1, a2))

def f(_):
    raise E(1, 2)

multiprocessing.Pool(1).map(f, (1,))
```

This gives below error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 496, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/contrnection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a2'
```

Any way to fix this? Similar issue is mentioned here: https://bugs.python.org/issue39751

Comment: "get hung" is a really bad description. It doesn't hang, in the sense of not progressing, it fails with a clear error message. The original bug gives a better description. Also, it provides a cause! So, simple question, have you tried adjusting this so that pickling works?

Comment: It works if you don't raise the exception and `print` it instead. So the problem is somewhere in the process of raising the exception.  Perhaps it has something to do with communicating with the main thread.

Comment: @sadasd Yeah, I understand. I just meant maybe it will help others zero in on the problem. Because just from reading the exception it wasn't obvious to me that the problem itself is in the actual raising of it.  But maybe it should have had.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 not even in `raise`, the pool worker target function captures the error, and attempts to send it back to main, and it's failing to un-pickle the `E` instance

Comment: When I run this it does actually hang instead of returning an error..

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with what the `__reduce__` function returns.

it is probably returning something like `(self.__class__, self.args)`
basically saying that to recreate this object pass in everything stored in self.args which is equal to ("12",).

Since there is no what of taking in the one string and splitting it back into the original args you probably don't want to mess with formatting before storage and should just implement a `__str__`.

```
class E(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        super().__init__(a1, a2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.args[0]}{self.args[1]}"
```

Edit: Added other possibilities I came up with but I don't recommend them.

```
# Change reduce
class E(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        super().__init__(f"{a1}{a2}")

    def __reduce__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (self.__class__, (self.args[0], ""))

# Optional arg this one is similar to Booboo's answer.
class E(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a1, a2=""):
        # I am assuming you have a more complex format string when not using the toy example
        # If so you need an if here.
        if a2:
            super().__init__(f"{a1}{a2}")
        else:
            super().__init__(a1)
```

Comment: I think you could be right with your analysis. But there could be huge semantic difference between computing a function of the two input arguments at object instantiation time versus when the exception is converted to a string, if it ever is. Clearly not in this case, but you get my point.

Comment: Could be, but because how BaseException is implemented, you don't really have a choice, args you pass into the super call get passed into your Custom Exception when re creating it. You could overwrite `__reduce__` but it could be much more disastrous.

Comment: See my answer. It's not geographically far from yours; just move your eyes down the page.

Comment: I still think knowing the goal is important, if it is to force required args in the exception and format the message, your solution doesn't do that. With `*args` you lose the method signature, what happens if you pass in 4 args etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to resolve this by defining `pickle` functions `__getstate__` and `__getstate__`, but they are not even getting invoked. However, the following should sidestep the problem until the issue, which I do believe is a problem with the `reduction.ForkingPickler` class, is resolved:

```py
import multiprocessing

class E(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 2:
            # Normal instantiation:
            Exception.__init__(self, '{}{}'.format(args[0], args[1]))
        else:
            # We are being pickled by the reduction.ForkingPickler:
            assert(len(args) == 1)
            Exception.__init__(self, args[0])

def f(_):
    raise E(1, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__': # Required for Windows
    try:
        multiprocessing.Pool(1).map(f, (1,))
    except E as e:
        print('Got E Exception:', e)
```

Prints:

```
Got E Exception: 12
```

Comment: seems to me like maybe `Exception.__new__` directly calls `cls.__init__`, which seemingly violates the ["`__init__()` is not called when unpickling an instance."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) idk... (being called with the results of `__reduce_ex__`)

Comment: @Aaron I don't think that would explain why my pickle functions are not even called.

Comment: not that this is any more or less of a hack, but just setting `self.args = (a1, a2)` in `__init__` seems cleaner to me... `self.args` is used by almost all exception types

Comment: @Aaron That is essentially the solution posed by Nathan Buckner. But see my comment to his answer.

Comment: I think his solution is better than what I was saying... setting `self.args` again directly after `super().__init__` seems like more of a hack. That said, I do think that is more how `Exception` is intended to be sub-classed. It retains the args you give it, and then you get to customize `__str__` or `__repr__` however you like.